# How to use gateway option with recap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I really like [recap](https://github.com/tomafro/recap) gem for applications deployment.

I have only one question: how to use the capistrano set: gateway, deploy@gateway.host option with recap?

In our projects we use virtualization and all the applications we are running in isolated containers and access to container possible only via ssh tunnel through gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple ssh feature, like this:

```
ssh -F path/to/config
```

Add the ssh config (ex. in config dir):

```
Host your_server_available_from_gateway_server
  User username
  ForwardAgent yes 
  ProxyCommand ssh gateway_server nc %h %p
```

In recap you should use this:

```
  set :ssh_options, { :config => 'path/to/config'}
```